# Can not send mail using laravel Mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-mail

i am using Laravel Mail to send mail but it shows 500 error with

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

i am using this code

```
\Mail::send('suppliers.mail',['name' => 'test'],function ($mail) {

   $mail->subject('Supplier Details');
   $mail->from('dump.test@gmail.com');
   $mail->to('dump.ajit@gmail.com');
});
```

i have already setup smtp server in ubuntu and configure mail.php in config folder of laravel, i can send mails using core php code

Comment: there is mail configuration file config/mail.php

Comment: Configure mail there

Comment: i did config mail server

Comment: use SMTP. there

Comment: For sending emails from localhost u need to install smtp

Comment: i have already setup smtp, i can send mails using core php code

Comment: enable error reporting. Debug your code

Comment: error log is already enabled @PrashantGPatil, i can see the errors from other pages

Comment: and when i debug app, debugs get stop at Mail::send(....)

Comment: @Jeet Have you checked the apache error log?? You could find the main reason behind the error there. If you could post the log we could help you more on this.

Comment: i'm not getting anything into apache error log @PaladiN

Comment: Did you setup SMTP details within `.env` file

Comment: try mailtrap and check the .env file. The mail settings in the .env file may not be right

Answer (score 0):

**In .env file**

- `MAIL_DRIVER=mail`
- `MAIL_HOST=localhost`
- `MAIL_PORT=587`

**Mail Function It's Working.**

```
$a = Mail::send('emails.reminder', [], function ($m) {
    $m->from('no-reply@domain.com');
    $m->to('vijaydeva@domain.com')->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```